# Shorten Copy and Paste VBA to paste filtered cells from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am pretty new to VBA and would like a bit of advice on the below, I am currently trying to filter certain dates then copy and paste them into a separate sheet to then =SUBTOTAL ect. The VBA works but does take slightly longer than desired.  Can anyone provide me a solution please, I've googled this and cannot get it to work when shortened.

```
Sheets("Paster").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AK$801").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
    xlFilterLastYear, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Hidden").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Overall").Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you use `.Copy` `.Paste` or `.Select` it's slowing you down significantly. You can make it slightly faster by turning off Screen Updating and Calculation. Then working with the ranges themselves is always going to be faster see below for how I got rid of using `.Select` you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Normally when you want to skip using `.copy` it's better to say to `This Range = That Range` then you can skip the clipboard completely but with filtered data it's a bit of a nightmare.

```
Sub CopyAndPaste()

    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim Paste As Worksheet, Hidden As Worksheet, Overall As Worksheet

    Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Paste = wbk.Worksheets("Paster")
    Set Hidden = wbk.Worksheets("Hidden")
    Set Overall = wbk.Worksheets("Overall")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        Paste.Range("$A$1:$AK$801").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastYear, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
        Paste.Cells.Copy

        Hidden.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfect, I assume the VBA will work the same for this year, this quarter ect.

Comment: @Fordy as far as i'm aware yes. You can find all the options [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xldynamicfiltercriteria.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Using select is very slow and is generally avoided if you can help it. I would recommend using a with statement to do all of the operations on a given sheet. Something like this should help. Instead of using select, try activate.

```
With Sheets("Paster").Range("$A$1:$AK$801")
    .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
    xlFilterLastYear, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
    .Copy
End With

With Sheets("Hidden")
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _ 
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False 'I just pasted into cell A1
End With
Sheets("Overall").Activate
```

I hope something like this will help! I do not know what type of data you are using, but it did copy a bunch of random generated data to the Hidden worksheet.

Another thing you can do to avoid the screen flashing/flickering is to turn screen updating off at the start of the macro and then turn it back on at the end.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' This should be the first line of a sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = True  ' This should be the last line of the sub
```